# Docker-compose and Java

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, jmx

I'm quite new to devops world, and I'm currently learning it. I'm  trying to start a docker-compose file with kafka and specific app that interacts with it, following one of the tutorials. It requires to start the java jar with the following parameters:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5555 \
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
   -jar build/libs/kafka-streams-scaling-all.jar
```

The question is - how do I run multiline command with options? I've tried it this way:

```
autoscaling:
  exec:
    command:
    - java
    - |
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5555 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
    -jar build/libs/kafka-streams-scaling-all.jar
```

But it returns   `in "./docker-compose.yml", line 75, column 9 could not find expected ':' in "./docker-compose.yml", line 76, column 9`

and some of the answers on the internet suggest to use > sign:

```
autoscaling:
  exec:
    command: >
      java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5555 \
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
      -jar build/libs/kafka-streams-scaling-all.jar
```

But docker doesn't seem to understand the "-" part of the command `expected <block end>, but found '-' in "./docker-compose.yml", line 74, column 7`

What is the best way to approach the running the java jars with options in docker-compose files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong indentation

```
<service_name>:
    command: |
      java \
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5555 \
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
      -jar build/libs/kafka-streams-scaling-all.jar
```

Comment: Thank you. All mistakes are gone. But seems that issue is a bit more complicated than I presumed. It asks for an image or a Dockerfile to start a service.